# Image analysis -- mapping two labeled Numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I have two Numpy arrays, array A and array B, with equal dimensions. Array A is a labelled array, where elements corresponding to the same "object" share the same value. Basically, what I'm trying to do is for each non-zero element in array B, if that element corresponds to a non-zero element in array A, re-label each element of that object (in array A) corresponding to the value from array B.

For example, if I have:

```
array A = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
           [3, 0, 0, 2, 0],
           [3, 3, 0, 2, 0]]

array B = [[0, 0, 4, 4, 4],
           [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
           [0, 4, 4, 0, 0],
           [0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
           [0, 0, 4, 4, 4],
           [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I want the resulting array C to look like:

```
array C = [[0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
           [0, 4, 4, 4, 0],
           [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
           [5, 0, 0, 4, 0],
           [5, 5, 0, 4, 0]]
```

EDIT: For my purposes, an 'object' in A cannot belong to more than one 'object' in B. For example, each non-zero element in A (above) is mapped to either a 4 or a 5 in B, but never both.

Sorry if that explanation is a bit convoluted. I would be grateful for any help or guidance anyone can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...I added a sample case. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Those `5s` at `C[4,0]` and `C[5,1]`, shouldn't those be `0s`? Similarly, the `4` at  `C[5,3]`. Can you check again?

Comment: Because the element at A[5,0] matches a 5 in B, I would like the rest of the elements belonging to label 3 in A to become 5s as well.

Comment: But still I don't really get how this is a well defined problem. How would you treat the case that an "object" in `A` belongs to two different objects in `B`? Or is this absolutely impossible?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out -- I should have mentioned that, for my purposes, an object in A cannot belong to more than one object in B.

Comment: So, it seems you are doing some kind of intersection between regions and then re-labelling. Have you looked into scikit based labelling : http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html. Some blob-based or even contour-based processing would be efficient here I think.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would use blob-based or contour-based processing to approach this problem?

Comment: As it stands, the way to solve your problem is to come up with a labels-to-labels mapping from labels of A to labels of B, then iterate over elements of A and apply the mapping. But there isn't a canonical way to map labels to labels. You said this was an image analysis problem. Could you tell us exactly what image analysis problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Right, so I have one image (A) which contains segmented objects, and a second image (B) which should serve as labels, or annotations, for the objects in A. The annotations from B can either be regions comprised of many elements, or just points comprised of a single element. Ultimately, I need the segmented objects in A that are annotated in B to take the value of those annotations. I think this is relatively straightforward for the regions, but less so for the points. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
C = np.zeros_like(A)
labels = set(A.flatten()) - {0}
for label in labels:
    mask = (A == label)
    value = set(B[mask].flatten()) - {0}
    C[mask] = [*value][0]
```

Maybe somebody can point more elegant way to find `value`?